# Anonymous function gives "undefined is not a function" in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When running the code below, I get an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at the line "back.ajax({". I've gone through the jQuery documentation and this seems like it should do the trick. Have also verified that jQuery is included and the browser recognizes "$". CURRYEAR is defined and all referred to elements exist. If I use this same code as a callback to .load() then it executes fine, but I need to execute synchronously as the while loop only executes once if called asynchronously.

Code:

```
function loadWL() {
  var back = $("#back-results");
  var numYears;
  var year;
  var count = 0;

  var wArr = [];
  var lArr = [];
  var dArr = [];

do {
    year = CURRYEAR - count;

    var standingsURL = STANDINGS.replace(" ", localStorage["leagueID"]);
    standingsURL = standingsURL.replace(",", year);

    var yqlStand = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + standingsURL + '"') + " #maincontainertblcell";

    //Load into the hidden pane
    var id;
    var self = this;
    back.html("");
    back.ajax({
        url: yqlStand,
        async: false
    }).done(function() {
        //Parse the number of years the league has been active
        if (count == 0) {
            numYears = $("select > option").length;
        }

        //Narrow to only the elements we need
        $(self).html($("#back-results tr .tableBody"));

        //Now traverse the back pane and store info
        $("#back-results > .tableBody a").closest("tr").each(function(index) {  
            id = urlToID($(this).find("a").attr('href'));                                       

            if (typeof wArr[id] == 'undefined') {
                wArr[id] = 0;
                lArr[id] = 0;
                dArr[id] = 0;
            }

            wArr[id] = wArr[id] + parseInt($(':nth-child(2)', this).text().trim(),10);                                  
            lArr[id] = lArr[id] + parseInt($(':nth-child(3)', this).text().trim(), 10);                                 
            dArr[id] = dArr[id] + parseInt($(':nth-child(4)', this).text().trim(), 10);                                 

            if (count == numYears-1) {
                arrayToLocal(wArr, "wins");
                arrayToLocal(lArr, "losses");
                arrayToLocal(dArr, "draws");
            }
        });

        count++;
        return;
    });
} while (count < numYears);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`back.ajax({...})` should be `$.ajax({...})`.

An ajax call is global, it's not tied to any particular object so you don't call it on a jQuery object, you call it on the jQuery namespace object.

---

In addition, you really ought to fix your ajax to work with `async: true` so it doesn't lock up the browser during the ajax calls.  That would require changing your while loop into a different type of structure that could sequence the async ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Ended up doing a load to find the number of pages to load, placing them into a queue, then calling a function that loads and recursively calls itself in the callback. Allows for serialized loading of the pages.